# Single layout for multiple SPA applications

Tags: npm, frontend, strapi, quasar-framework, micro-frontend

I'm starting a project where I will be making a suite of applications. Each application will be its own SPA, hosted on its own domains.

However, each application should use the same layout - nav bar up-top and pull out drawer on the left side. All the text and menu options should be handled dynamically (depending on the spa using it). What is the best way to go about this? How can I make a single layout component that can be used across multiple applications?

Please keep in mind that each SPA should have the ability to be developed independently - one might be ReactJS another might be VueJs or Angular.

Also, my employer does not want to use a micro frontend framework. I was hoping someone that is more experienced can help me out here and throw some ideas my way. Would I make this an npm package?

I would like to use [strapi.io](https://strapi.io/) as my content manager, and I want to build the [layout in quasar.js](https://quasar.dev/layout/layout) (but maybe I should build my own with no framework so each spa does not have too many dependencies IDK).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If you use several frameworks, each of them will have its own code, nothing is interchangeable. Specifically, Quasar is directly based on Vue. One thing you may have in common is the CSS, maybe though TailwindCSS if you do not want to write your own.

Comment: Hey @WoJ, I actually ended up using Webpacks5's Module federation feature to share components (navBar and more) between applications.